# Set variable to data attribute value instead of NaN

Tags: jquery, nan, custom-data-attribute

The value of the data attribute `date-total-cost` is `100`.

```
var total_cost = $('.output--lisence-cost').data('date-total-cost');
```

but the variable `total_cost` returns `NaN`

How do I set the variable to return a the number of the data field?

**UPDATE...**

i'm also setting value of the data attribute in the following function...

`function Cost() {
 $('.output--lisence-cost').attr('data-total-cost',totalSeatsCost);
}`

the var `totalSeatsCost` is set using a range slider.

Comment: @vijayP Normally that is the problem when there's confusion between `attr()` and `data()` however note that in this case the first part of the attribute is `date`, not `data`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - yes..haven't read it properly..!

Comment: jQuery `.data` returnes data stored the same method or attributes with the prefix `data-`... for your specific case use `.attr` instead and don't fogert to fix the typo

Comment: thanks for noticing that typo @vijay :) My returned output is now `0`. I've updated my original post with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `attr` instead of `data`

```
var total_cost = $('.output--lisence-cost').attr('date-total-cost');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `total_cost` will only be `NaN` if the value you *place in it* is `NaN`. If you expect the value to be filled it would be worth investigating the code which is setting the value.

That said, you can use Javascripts' falsy nature to coerce `NaN` to a default value by using the logical or operator, like this:

```js
var total_cost = NaN; // $('.output--lisence-cost').data('date-total-cost');
console.log(total_cost || 100); // returns '100' if value was undefined/false/NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

The [API reference for `.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) says this (emphasis mine):

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the
>   jQuery collection, **as set by data(name, value)** or by an HTML5 data-*
>   attribute.

In other words, it does not manipulate the value to convert it to number.

The only solution is to not insert `NaN` in the first place—once there you simply cannot recover the original value. How could you?

```
> console.log(Number('Foo'));
NaN
> console.log(Number('Bar'));
NaN
> console.log(Number('Apples!'));
NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of data is treated as string. I think you are trying to do some calucation based on this value.

Try to convert return data to number through:

```
+total_cost
```

or

```
Number(total_cost)
```